# TabLayout with Activity in android like Tab with Pager

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-studio-2.2

I am a novice in Android Development. I want to make a tab like a `ViewPager` using `Activity`. [Sample of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ2hc.gif)

I have tried the following code...

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
        instantiateTab();
    }

    public void instantiateTab() {
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());

        final int[] ICONS = new int[]{
                R.drawable.ic_chat_bubble_outline_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_library_add_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_notifications_none_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_person_outline_black_24dp,
        };

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(ICONS[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(ICONS[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(ICONS[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(ICONS[3]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(ICONS[4]);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 0) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, MessageActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 1) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, FindjobActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 2) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, PostProjectActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 3) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 4) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
```

`MessageActivity` extend above class for instantiate tab in
    `activity_message.xml`

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message2);
        instantiateTab();
    }
```

**activity_message.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contentMessage"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/common_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you question is

Comment: normally we use fragment , tab and viewpager to made slider like view, but i want to made same by using activity tab and viewpager...even i also dont  know what i hav eto ask, but may be you guys could understand and solve my issue...thank you